# Clear GET params from URL

Tags: web-server, web

I have a simple GET webform that takes in text. Once that text is submitted the URL permanently displays the text as the parameter. This causes echoing issues when I check the input from the web form; the string I am looking for is always found because the URL is never cleared. I cannot use an HTTP redirect and am looking for a way to do this based upon code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because their isn't even the word "Arduino", not even once, in the question. How is this suppose to be on topic?

Comment: @DatHa I am using the Arduino EthernetClient and EthernetServer

Comment: Try Stack Overflow

Comment: @DatHa the forum is specifically for Arduino so I assumed it was generally understood any programming questions were related to Arduino programming

Comment: Not my problem. The question has to be clear.

Be specific : program, schematic, part used.

See : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This can only be done with a redirect. If you cannot use a redirect (because something about your web server doesn't let you) then you need to re-think your website design.

Answer (score 1):

this is exaclty waht get are supposed to do. Use a POST or use a redirect; a POST is way better as the "back" button of the browser will take care of it